Page Number & Chapter Title Number Alignment
With the following setup, the page numbers and the chapter numbers are not aligned. They are both supposed to be centered, but clearly one is not.
\documentclass[10pt,titlepage,openany,largepost]{octavo}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox, everyshi, xifthen}
\usepackage[cam, noinfo, a4, center]{crop}
\usepackage[cleardoublepage=empty]{scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 

% Same page chapter
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{cpt}
\newcommand\myc[2]
{\stepcounter{cpt}
  \chapter[#1]{\Roman{cpt}\linebreak{}#2}}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\centering\bfseries\scshape}
{}
{18pt}
{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{24pt}{18pt}

\begin{document}
\myc{Beyond this, how is it possible to go?}{Beyond this, how is it possible to go?}
Lest he should be accused of
outrageous audacity in presuming to question such an imposing consensus of
critical verdicts, the present translator would first allege the strange phenomenon that this “standard” and unsurpassable rendering, the one which, according to Mme.\ Longworth Chambrun (\emph{Giovanni Florio}, 2922, Pp: 82)
has been consecrated by the approval of three centuries of English readers
was, as a matter of fact, completely ignored by them for over two hundred
years, that it was through the mediation of Charles Cotton that Montaigne
reached the English public during that long interval, that William Hazlitt,
the son of the great essayist (Mr.\ Trechmann, by his manner of referring to
him in his “Translator’s Preface,” seems to be confusing him with his father), in introducing his revision of Cotton's version, quotes words strangely
parallel to those of Mr.\ Saintsbury, saying that it “fully comes up to the

\myc{Beyond this, how is it possible to go?}{Beyond this, how is it possible to go?}
Lest he should be accused of
outrageous audacity in presuming to question such an imposing consensus of
critical verdicts, the present translator would first allege the strange phenomenon that this “standard” and unsurpassable rendering, the one which, according to Mme.\ Longworth Chambrun (\emph{Giovanni Florio}, 2922, Pp: 82)
has been consecrated by the approval of three centuries of English readers
was, as a matter of fact, completely ignored by them for over two hundred
years, that it was through the mediation of Charles Cotton that Montaigne
reached the English public during that long interval, that William Hazlitt,
the son of the great essayist (Mr.\ Trechmann, by his manner of referring to
him in his “Translator’s Preface,” seems to be confusing him with his father), in introduci
\end{document}

One of the pages:

What might be the problem?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I am so sorry! Of course. Question edited.

With your code, I cannot reproduce your problem. I've added a vertical line to the text area to show the middle axis and get: https://i.imgur.com/hW9yG3u.png. So I can only guess, that in your real document you have some relevant line endings not commented: → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat
